# Android - How to set an action bar tab as first selected?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Here my code:

```
    Tab tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText(R.string.friends)
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<FriendsFragment>(this, "friends_list",
                            FriendsFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText(R.string.home)
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<UserHomeFragment>(this, "user_home",
                            UserHomeFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setText(R.string.highscores)
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<HighscoresFragment>(this, "highscores",
                            HighscoresFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

How can i set the "UserHome" as first tab displayed/selected? I want it in the middle like now.
So when my "TabActivity" start it will be like this:
Friends - **Home** - Highscores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options, the easiest with your current implementation be to just set it as the selected tab when adding the tab to the action bar with [ActionBar#addTab(Tab tab, boolean setSelected)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#addTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab,%20boolean%29).

Alternatively you could set the selection with [ActionBar#setSelectedNavigationItem(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29).